# Does mysql process queries involving multiple partitions parallely or serially for each partition?

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-partitioning

This is my table schema.

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `account_id` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,    
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=25600033 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
 PARTITION BY LIST (account_id)
 (PARTITION p0 VALUES IN (1) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p1 VALUES IN (2) ENGINE = InnoDB,
  PARTITION p2 VALUES IN (3) ENGINE = InnoDB)
```

The query is

```
select * from users where account_id in (1,2);
```

Does sql server will check in partion 1 & 2 parallely or one by one??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one by one.

There is no parallelism in a single connection in MySQL.  Not for `UNION`, not for `PARTITIONs`.  Not (so far) in version 8.0.

There is probably no performance to be gained by `PARTITION BY LIST`.  Further comments:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/partitionmaint